# wordpress redirecting to the root url instead of subfolder url when saving settings/options

Tags: wordpress

I have customized both wordpress address and site address as the following:

WordPress Address (URL)  `https://example.com/blog`

Site Address (URL):  `https://example.com/blog`

Everything work fine, when I visit the blog I can see the articles, I can navigate, etc,

I can even access my wp-admin through https://example.com/blog/wp-admin, navigate the dashboard etc,

The only issue is the redirect URL when I'm saving something like editing the theme and click "save" or editing the general settings:

for example, if I go to **Settings > General** and try to update any option, after clicking the **"save"** button it submits the form then redirect me to:

https://**example.com/wp-admin**/options-general.php?settings-updated=true

instead of

https://**example.com/blog/wp-admin**/options-general.php?settings-updated=true

Here is what my .htaccess looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also, when I go to the theme customizer and hover over the "exit/close" button it shows the wrong URL (without /blog)

[image]

The weird thing is, that there is another button to customize the theme in the dashboard:

[image]

When I use this button and I click close/cancel of the customizer the return url is correct, so I noticed that accessing the customizer through the dashboard menu has a parameter ?return=/wp-admin  while the blue button above has not!

for some reason, if the param ?return=/wp-admin is in the link, wordpress is redirecting to the main domain and ignoring the subfolder url!

Comment: update your permalinks

Comment: @ShantunParmar I updated the permalinks but it doesn't solve the issue, by the way the permalinks page works (when I submit the form) but if I go for example to Settings>General, the form fails, when I inspect the form I see `<input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/wp-admin/options-general.php">` it should be `/blog/wp-admin/options-general.php` i think, so somehow wordpress (in specific pages) is sending these kind of variables and that's the issue

Comment: also while I have my urls pointing to /blog, wordpress physically isn't under a /blog folder, I use a reverse-proxy to make wordpress blog as part of my app which is a Rails app

Comment: I have this exact same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @hjelmeir to be honest with you I don't really remember if I ever found a solution or not, because I moved away from wordpress due to the issues that happened one after one even though I found some hacks, I wrote an article about what I did with wordpress at that time here https://medium.com/@technoblogueur/wordpress-blog-for-ruby-on-rails-the-configuration-that-worked-for-me-a8a7a989a68d I'm not sure if this will help but you can read through and find out :)

Comment: @medBouzid Thank you sharing your article. I will check it out

Answer (score 0):

**Solution #1 - Code Change**

This is how I fixed this and it may not be the right way to about it but gets the job done.

If you see the documentation of [wp_referer_field](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_referer_field/) you will find its defined in wp-includes/functions.php

So what I do was replace

```
$referer_field = '<input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="' . esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) . '" />';
```

with

```
$referer_field = '<input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/blog' . esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) . '" />';
```

It has the extra path i.e /blog in the value attribute of the hidden field which solved my purpose.

**Solution #2 - Rewrite Rule(Not tested)**

I had to do solution 1 because my main website already had a rewrite rule and I could not modify it to rewrite the missing paths to mysite.com/blog. Maybe the Rewrite rules in the original question are also not set up correctly or may have other config files conflicting with Rewrite rules.

And if that's not your case, you should try writing the correct rewrite rule
as per WordPress's official article -

https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/#method-i-without-url-change

i.e

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_subdir/$1
```